# How to read XML response in specific character code in Java

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, mediawiki, domdocument

I use Wikimedia API Sandbox for Japanese.

[Japanese Version](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5%3aApiSandbox)

[English Version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox)

I send a HTTP request to Wikimedia and I get a result formed in XML. 
When I try to send a request and get a result on API Sandbox Webpage, there is no character corruption in a result.

But when I get a result in Java, a result includes character corruptions.

I cannot assign a specific character code in XML file.

How can I assign a result a specific character code?
How can I resolve my problem?

```
  try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db
                .parse(new URL(
                        "http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=xml&cllimit=10&titles="
                                + key).openStream());
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList queryList = root.getChildNodes();
        Node query = queryList.item(0);
        if (query instanceof Element) {
            Element queryEle = (Element) query;
            NodeList pagesList = queryEle.getChildNodes();
            Node pgs = pagesList.item(0);
            if (pgs instanceof Element) {
                Element pagesElement = (Element) pgs;
                NodeList pageList = pagesElement.getChildNodes();
                Node page = pageList.item(0);
                if (page instanceof Element) {
                    Element pageElement = (Element) page;
                    String title = pageElement.getAttribute("title");
                    title = new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (SAXException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Now I send a [request](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=categories&format=xml&cllimit=10&titles=%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6), I got a result whose page title is "大学". But in Java, it shows "??".

I use above code for Android Application.

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your Java code.

Comment: Remove this line: `title = new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");` and tell us what you expect, what you get instead, and how you're displaying what you get.

Answer (score 0):

`title = new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");` can be left out.

It worked for me, for key=1 (receiving UTF-8). I have a UTF-8 Linux PC though. Maybe you did not output in a UTF-8 context or so. Try write the Document to a file.

You could do more inspection:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("...").openConnection();
... connection.getContentEncoding();
... connection.getContentType();
InputStream in = connection.openStream();
```